# How to overcome <customErrors> error in a .NET remote hosting environment?

Tags: .net

I am hoping that someone around here already confronted this error and is an easy fix. We are unable to see the real error, and we have done all that we think we can do.  Any ideas, apparently we cannot see the error because of security.  We are always able to setup hosting internally but we want to avoid that.  Any ideas?  The screenshot of the error below.

[.NET Remote Error Screenshot http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/6-24-20092-34-27PM.png](http://cp.images.s3.amazonaws.com/ForumImages/6-24-20092-34-27PM.png)

One more thing, this hosting environment is remote for the development team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elmah!

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

This is an error logging tool that captures unhandled exceptions and writes them out to your database. It will even write out the entire stack trace. It doesn't require any coding and can be inserted into a running application.   It just requires some configuration in your web.config and a few database tables (scripts are provided).

This way you can display custom, pretty error pages while still having access to your exception logs.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file turn custom errors off:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">

    </customErrors>
```

Please note this is **not** the recommended approach. You should probably keep it as it is and instead take a look at windows event logs to see if any asp.net errors have been logged there.

Long term you would probably benefit from some kind of exception handling / logging strategy:

- [ELMAH](http://www.raboof.com/projects/Elmah/)
- [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx) (Exception Handling Application Block)

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions in the first yellow box, you should not be seeing this page.  Go back and ensure you set your customErrors mode="Off".

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `system.web` element in your `Web.config` file:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Make sure to remove it once you fix the problem.

If it doesn't help, there might be a syntax error or other problem with Web.config on the server.  In particular, you might be referencing an assembly that the server doesn't have; if so, copy it to the bin folder.